# If $t<0$, what is $t\sum a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $t$ be a nonpositive real number (i.e. $t<0$) and $\{a_n\}$ be a nonnegative sequence if $$\sum a_n<\infty$$ then how do we prove or disprove that $$t\sum a_n<\infty?$$

Comment: In this given case, $\sum a_n$ is just a real number. You could write $s=\sum a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and since $t$ is some other real number, we have $ts=st\in\mathbb{R}$. (Note we're not considering $\infty$ to be a real number!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a_n \geq 0$ by assumption, we have:
$$ \infty > \sum a_n \geq 0  $$
Now, if you multiply for some real number $t < 0$, the result will be:
$$ - \infty < t \sum a_n \leq 0 < + \infty $$
Notice that the sum is not infinite, because you have multiplied by a *finite* value $t$.

Comment: Nice ans straight forward answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case, $a_n \ge 0$ and thus $|a_n| = a_n$. You trivially have that
$$ \sum_n |a_n| = \sum_n a_n < \infty . $$
Now, for negative $t \in \mathbb{R}$ you have
$$ t \sum_n a_n \le | t \sum_n a_n | \le |t| \left| \sum_n a_n \right| = |t| \sum_n |a_n | = |t| \sum_n a_n < \infty $$
(the middle equality is because that $\forall n : a_n \ge 0$). 
In a similar manner you obtain that
$$ -\infty < t \sum_n a_n $$
and thus you deduce that $\sum_n a_n < \infty$ converges, using the [Direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: I like the details. Thanks